# Problem with upgrade from 4.5.5 in drupal

Tags: drupal, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from civicrm 4.5.5. I follow instructions of https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/ but any time I do the upgrade I get the screen with skip or retry buttons that doesn't work. I don't know if the ugrade was completed.

[image: this screen results in any upgrade try]

Then if I go to the civicrm page I see the new version number (4.6.34) but menu disappeared and I can't continue working with the previous data, contribution pages, mailing, etc.

what could be the problem?

[[image: Civicrm home[2]]

Comment: Can you check in CiviCRM logs (sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigLog/) for any error?

Comment: Yes, but there aren't any error i in the moment of the last upgrade

Comment: Was the upgrade successful? Are there any JavaScript errors on browser console? Try clearing Drupal and CiviCRM cache

Comment: At this moment the upgrade was not succesful. I cleared caches, removed contents of sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c and the file sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini

Comment: You will need to upgrade CiviCRM first. Check for any console error on [yourdomainname]/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1

Comment: Yes, I give some more information:I rebuild menus and database triggers. The problem appears to have a solution from I changed theme from AT Commerce 7.x-3.2 to Seven 7.56. This change allowed access to civicrm home, I could see the menu, and appears to work. I visited ?q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 and the upgrading process started to move step by step from version to version. The page stops with a message lie this [Executed: Finish Upgrade DB to 4.6.alpha4]

Comment: Finally the upgrade was succesful. Thanks for the advice. There perstist problems when I use theme 'At commerce. ' I have to close the question?

Comment: Great! Yes, Write answer to your own question the fix that you did to overcome the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem overcomes when deactivated AT Commerce 7.x-3.2 as the enabled theme. Then buttons and menus worked. Upgrade was successful finally.